# Store Parameter in a Variable for report viewer

Tags: asp.net, sql, c#-4.0

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {   ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
            ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(@"http://123.abc/Reportserver");
            ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Test/Development/Details";
            ReportViewer1.ShowParameterPrompts = true;
            ReportViewer1.ShowPrintButton = true;


            ReportParameter[] rptParams = new ReportParameter[1];
            SqlConnection MA = new SqlConnection(MedA);
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select distinct Users from PROD.Users Where Username ='" + this.Username + "'", MA);         
            SqlDataAdapter dataAadpter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dataAadpter.Fill(ds);
            rptParams[0] = new ReportParameter("UserID", ds); //this.Username
            ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(rptParams);
            ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
            ReportViewer1.AsyncRendering = false;
            ReportViewer1.SizeToReportContent = true;
        }
```

I am not able to pass the parameter. I am trying to get the user key from logged in user. Can anyone help me

Comment: How is your Report Server security configured?  Windows Auth or Forms Auth.  If it is windows auth why do you need to pass in the user?  Are you hopping to another machine?

Comment: @Daniel I am using Form Auth. I have a login page from where I get the username. Using the user name I get the key from DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First store the username from your Login screen like below:

```
Session["LoggedInUser"] = txtUsername.Text.Trim();
```

Then paste the below code in your report page:

```
  protected String Username
    {
        get
        {
            return Convert.ToString(Session["LoggedInUser"]);
        }
    }
```

In page load write the below code for you report:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {   ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
                ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(@"http://123.abc/Reportserver");
                ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Test/Development/Details";
                ReportViewer1.ShowParameterPrompts = true;
                ReportViewer1.ShowPrintButton = true;

        ReportParameter[] rptParams = new ReportParameter[1];
        SqlConnection MA = new SqlConnection(MedA);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select distinct Users from PROD.Users Where Username ='" + this.Username + "'", MA);         
        SqlDataAdapter dataAadpter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dataAadpter.Fill(ds);
        rptParams[0] = new ReportParameter("UserID", ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString()); //this.Username
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(rptParams);
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
        ReportViewer1.AsyncRendering = false;
        ReportViewer1.SizeToReportContent = true;
    }
```